# Как создать лицензионный сервер?

Tags: windows

Есть программа под Windows. Желание генерировать лицензионные ключи руками нет. 
Предполагается создание лицензионного сервера, который будет делать проверку двух одновременно запущенных копий программы в онлайне.

Вот алгоритм.

> 1. Пользователь покупает лицензионный ключ.
> 2. На сервере  генерируется случайный ключ и прописывается в базу.
> 3. Пользователь вводит ключ в программу. Программа помещает его в
>    свою базу на ПК.
> 4. Юзер запускает программу.
> 5. Программа авторизуется на лицензионном сервере с помощью
>    лицензионного ключа.    Если во время
>    сессии произойдет еще одна авторизация
>    с этим же ключом,    данный ключ будет
>    деактивирован.

Остается вопрос с подменой в файле hosts Windows лицензионного сервера на фейковый.

По всей видимости лицензионный сервер должен в ответе на удачную попытку авторизации отдавать некий уникальный параметр и программа
должна его распознать как сигнал с настоящего лицензионного сервера.

Но что это может быть за параметр? Может есть у кого какие идеи на этот счет? Как обезопаситься от подмены хоста?

Comment: Никак. На своей машине пользователь может сделать что угодно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- У подобного подхода, на мой взгляд, больше проблем, чем пользы.
- Представьте себе, например, что произошла ситуация двойной авторизации с одним и тем же ключом. Вы в этом случае хотите перманентно *деактивировать ключ* или просто сделать так, чтобы один из запущенных клиентов *перестал работать?*

> - Первый вариант **не работает** на практике, поскольку вы не сможете обеспечить `100%` синхронизацию состояния сессии на клиенте и знания про эту сессию на сервере (то есть, скажем, клиент сообщил, что он открыл сессию, а после этого у пользователя вырубился свет).
> - Второй вариант требует постоянного подключения к серверу, а также выполнение `push / poll` для синхронизации текущего статуса лицензии. Помножьте сложность этого требования на необходимость обеспечения `Three Nines+` надежности для вашего сервера, проблемы `firewall'ов`, проблемы с безопасностью передачи сведений про лицензионные ключи, проблемы `latency` и вспомните про сложности использования в схожем решении, которое предложила компания `Ubisoft` — в вашем случае они тоже будут. Вы к этому готовы?

- Мне кажется, что разумнее для вашего продукта явно указать в `EULA` о невозможности запуска более одной копии продукта для одного лицензионного ключа.

> - Те, кто захотят сломать ваш продукт, сделают это в любом случае, а тех пользователей, которые сознательно купили лицензию для него, не стоит проверять на честность — это, скорее всего, приведет к ухудшению стабильности вашего приложения без получения каких-либо ощутимых бонусов.

Comment: спасибо, за советы. Тоже прихожу к мысли, что накладный вариант получается

Answer (score 0):

Для избежания подмены сервера можно использовать сертификаты, в этом случае подлинность сервера будет подтверждаться третьей стороной, посмотри тут: [`Public key certificate. Extended Validation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Extended_Validation).

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже приняли ответ, но я все же посоветую: 
Можно защищать приложения с помощью специально разработанного апи разными конторами. Которые предоставляют как физические ключи защиты, так и софтварные. Наша компания пользуется услугами гуардант. Саму компанию не буду рекламировать, потому как у них также баги и задержки с выпуском исправлений, но мои нарекания не связаны с устаканевшимся функционалом.